# How to convert string to java class and invoke it

Tags: java, selenium

Currently i'm writing a driver script that will read the java class names from excel sheet and should execute that class based on the runmanager field(Y/N).

My Excel sheet look like below. Currently i can able to read the class name as string. Now i want to convert that string into class and invoke that.

Please help me to resolve that issue.

Here is the table structure of my excel sheet:

```
Classname   Runmanager(Y/N)
Testclass1  Y
Testclass2  N
Testclass3  Y
```

Comment: could you provide the code you have come up with so far?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far. And what do you mean by "invoke" a class? Do you just want to create one object of that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Class.forName() method:

```
    String className = "java.lang.String";
    Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
```

Then you can call the newInstance() method (if the class has an empty constructor):

```
    Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
```

and then - since you know what kind of classes you have in your excel - you can check the class and cast appropriately:

```
    if (obj instanceof String) {
        String value = (String) obj;
    }
```